# Rendering a Table based on option tag in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm trying to render a table that displays data related to an option element the user selects from a dropdown. Basically the table is only supposed show info based on their selection, but I (being an entry-level programmer) have no idea how to do this. Any ideas? Here's my code:

```
<style>
    .tableContainer {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();

      $("#renderBtn").on("click", function(){
        $(".tableContainer").css("display", "block");
      });
    });
</script>

                 <select class="js-example-basic-single">
                    <optgroup label="HTML">
                        @foreach ($assetList as $asset)
                            @if($asset->asset_type_id == 1)
                                <option data-id="{{$asset->asset_id}}" value="{{$asset->title}}">{{$asset->title}}</option>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label="PDF">
                        @foreach ($assetList as $asset)
                            @if($asset->asset_type_id == 2)
                                <option data-id="{{$asset->asset_id}}" value="{{$asset->title}}">{{$asset->title}}</option>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label="VIDEO">
                        @foreach ($assetList as $asset)
                            @if($asset->asset_type_id == 3)
                                <option data-id="{{$asset->asset_id}}" value="{{$asset->title}}">{{$asset->title}}</option>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </optgroup>
                </select>
                <button id="renderBtn" class="btn">Render Table</button>
                <div id="tableContainer" class="tableContainer">
                    <table id="userAssetTable" class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Asset ID</td>
                                <td>Asset</td>
                                <td>Action Type</td>
                                <td>Message</td>
                                <td>Created At</td>
                                <td>Updated At</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        @foreach ($actionList as $action)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$action->asset_id}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    @foreach ($assetList as $asset)
                                        @if($action->asset_id == $asset->asset_id)
                                            {{$asset->title}}
                                        @endif
                                    @endforeach
                                </td>
                                <td>{{$action->action_type_id}}</td>
                                <td>{{$action->message}}</td>
                                <td>{{$action->created_at}}</td>
                                <td>{{$action->updated_at}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </table>
                </div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this with Ajax? Is that data coming from server after a selection is made?

Comment: Yes; I have a server running, which is where the data is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using the *data-id* attribute in the *option* elements, then working your way through Javascript? Ex:

```
<option data-id="exampleID">Option1</option>
<script>
 *Use a loop to filter through data here*
</script>
```